# Rails Meta_Search: search in associated model's show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-associations, meta-search

I have a model trip.rb

```
 class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
 end
```

And I am using meta_search to search trips on it's index page.

```
  <%= form_for @search do |f| %>             

     <%= f.collection_select :location_id_equals, Location.order('country ASC').all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true, :prompt => "All locations" %> 

     <%= f.collection_select :categories_id_equals, Category.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true, :prompt => "All categories"  %> 

     <%= f.collection_select :budget_id_in, Budget.all, :id, :name, :include_blank => true, :prompt => "All budgets" %> 

     <%= submit_tag "Find", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %> </li>

  <% end %>
```

trips_controller.rb

```
  def index   
    @search = Trip.search(params[:search])  
  end
```

Category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :trips
end
```

Now the things is I want to add search also on **categories show page** and search **associated trips there.**

The problem is I'm not an expert and not really sure how to do this properly.

Can someone point on the right direction ? 
Thanks.